# Azure SDK Compute Emulator Initialization error

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-sdk-.net

I am getting thefollowing error when trying to open Azure Storage Emulator - v4.2. I am using Visual Studio 2015, SQL Server 2014 and Azure SDK 2.7.1. 
[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhuzL.png).

When I hit OK then I get the following screen.
[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzEPH.png)

I have tried reinstalling azure sdk a couple of times.

Comment: Have you tested the workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Try starting Visual Studio as administrator, start debugging the application from VS and the emulator should work ok.